# purescript FFI types to safely import javascript functions

Tags: javascript, ffi, purescript

Trying out the purescript FFI, and following the "Purescript By Example" book, I have created a JS file to get the head of an array:

```
exports.head = function(arr) {
  return arr[0];
};
```

And in purescript I declare a new `Undefined` data for the type signature of head to indicate the `undefined` returned when the array is empty:

```
foreign import data Undefined :: Type -> Type
foreign import head :: forall a. Array a -> Undefined a
```

Now, how do I use a value of type `Undefined a`? What function do I need to define to *extract* the `a` so I can use it elsewhere? 
The example in the book follows by just defining a function:

```
foreign import isUndefined :: forall a. Undefined a -> Boolean
```

as:

```
exports.isUndefined = function(value) {
  return value === undefined;
};
```

but I need something like:

```
foreign import getFromUndefined :: forall a. Undefined a -> a
```

Is it possible to write that function in JS, and in that case, what to return when the `Undefined a` is really `undefined`?
Or alternatively, can I redefine the type `Undefined a` to allow patern matching over it to *extract* the a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement something like

```
foreign import fromUndefinedWithDefault :: forall a. a -> Undefined a -> a
```

instead by reusing what you did to define `isUndefined`.

The type you wrote cannot be implemented because safely, because I could use it to define

```
bad :: Void
bad = getFromUndefined (head [])
```